# Is there a program to copy full folder path directories?

Tags: windows, text-editor, text-processing, copy-paste, xpath

Does anyone know of a program to do this?

Basically you have a folder on your computer

And subfolders inside of that

Possibly more subfolders in those

Some text file names + images in those

Is there a program that copies all of the structure hierarchy so I could import it into a program like workflowy?

Example file structure:

[image]

Example paste result in workflowy / dynalist

[image]

Example paste result in a .txt file

[image]

Or would anyone know what resources I could use to script this?

Comment: Of course with your user name you could always use `os.walk`

Comment: thanks I'll look into this anaconda package as well :)

Comment: `os` it a standard python package that is also in Anaconda, `os.walk` recursively traverses a directory tree in each sub-directory having a `root`, `dirs` and `files` list, `root` being the path to the current directory being walked, `dirs` a list of the directories in it and `files`, _you guessed_, a list of the files in that directory. Very, very powerful and useful. It is also worth looking at `glob.glob("**")` in python 3.5+

Comment: thanks steve I'll definitely check all of this out. the more you know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The windows command: `tree /A /F > temp.txt` gets very close to what you are asking for.

```
|   temp.txt
|   
+---build
|       __init__.py
|       
+---lib
|   |   activex.py
|   |   activexwrapper.py
|   |   anchors.py
|   |   busy.py
|   |   buttonpanel.py
|   |   buttons.py
|   |   calendar.py
|   |   CDate.py
|   |   ClickableHtmlWindow.py
|   |   colourdb.py
|   |   colourselect.py
|   |   colourutils.py
|   |   combotreebox.py
|   |   customtreectrl.py
|   |   delayedresult.py
|   |   dialogs.py
|   |   docview.py
|   |   dragscroller.py
|   |   embeddedimage.py
|   |   eventStack.py
|   |   eventwatcher.py
|   |   evtmgr.py
|   |   expando.py
|   |   fancytext.py
|   |   filebrowsebutton.py
|   |   flashwin.py
|   |   flashwin_old.py
|   |   flatnotebook.py
|   |   floatbar.py
|   |   foldmenu.py
|   |   foldpanelbar.py
|   |   gestures.py
|   |   graphics.py
|   |   gridmovers.py
|   |   grids.py
|   |   hyperlink.py
|   |   iewin.py
|   |   iewin_old.py
|   |   imagebrowser.py
|   |   imageutils.py
|   |   infoframe.py
|   |   inspection.py
|   |   intctrl.py
|   |   itemspicker.py
|   |   langlistctrl.py
|   |   layoutf.py
|   |   msgpanel.py
|   |   multisash.py
|   |   mvctree.py
|   |   myole4ax.idl
|   |   myole4ax.tlb
|   |   newevent.py
|   |   nvdlg.py
|   |   pdfwin.py
|   |   pdfwin_old.py
|   |   platebtn.py
|   |   plot.py
|   |   popupctl.py
|   |   printout.py
|   |   progressindicator.py
|   |   pydocview.py
|   |   pyshell.py
|   |   rcsizer.py
|   |   resizewidget.py
|   |   rightalign.py
|   |   rpcMixin.py
|   |   scrolledpanel.py
|   |   sheet.py
|   |   shell.py
|   |   sized_controls.py
|   |   softwareupdate.py
|   |   splashscreen.py
|   |   splitter.py
|   |   statbmp.py
|   |   stattext.py
|   |   throbber.py
|   |   ticker.py
|   |   ticker_xrc.py
|   |   utils.py
|   |   wordwrap.py
|   |   wxcairo.py
|   |   wxPlotCanvas.py
|   |   wxpTag.py
|   |   __init__.py
|   |   
|   +---agw
|   |   |   advancedsplash.py
|   |   |   aquabutton.py
|   |   |   artmanager.py
|   |   |   balloontip.py
|   |   |   buttonpanel.py
|   |   |   cubecolourdialog.py
|   |   |   customtreectrl.py
|   |   |   flatmenu.py
|   |   |   flatnotebook.py
|   |   |   floatspin.py
|   |   |   fmcustomizedlg.py
|   |   |   fmresources.py
|   |   |   foldpanelbar.py
|   |   |   fourwaysplitter.py
|   |   |   genericmessagedialog.py
|   |   |   gradientbutton.py
|   |   |   hyperlink.py
|   |   |   hypertreelist.py
|   |   |   infobar.py
|   |   |   knobctrl.py
|   |   |   labelbook.py
|   |   |   multidirdialog.py
|   |   |   peakmeter.py
|   |   |   piectrl.py
|   |   |   pybusyinfo.py
|   |   |   pycollapsiblepane.py
|   |   |   pygauge.py
|   |   |   pyprogress.py
|   |   |   rulerctrl.py
|   |   |   shapedbutton.py
|   |   |   shortcuteditor.py
|   |   |   speedmeter.py
|   |   |   supertooltip.py
|   |   |   thumbnailctrl.py
|   |   |   toasterbox.py
|   |   |   ultimatelistctrl.py
|   |   |   xlsgrid.py
|   |   |   zoombar.py
|   |   |   __init__.py
|   |   |   
|   |   +---aui
|   |   |       auibar.py
|   |   |       auibook.py
|   |   |       aui_constants.py
|   |   |       aui_switcherdialog.py
|   |   |       aui_utilities.py
|   |   |       dockart.py
|   |   |       framemanager.py
|   |   |       tabart.py
|   |   |       tabmdi.py
|   |   |       __init__.py
|   |   |       
|   |   +---data
|   |   |       default_help_text.html
|   |   |       ShortcutEditor_1.png
|   |   |       ShortcutEditor_1_thumb.png
|   |   |       ShortcutEditor_2.png
|   |   |       ShortcutEditor_2_thumb.png
|   |   |       ShortcutEditor_3.png
|   |   |       ShortcutEditor_3_thumb.png
|   |   |       ShortcutEditor_4.png
|   |   |       ShortcutEditor_4_thumb.png
|   |   |       
|   |   +---persist
|   |   |       persistencemanager.py
|   |   |       persist_constants.py
|   |   |       persist_handlers.py
|   |   |       __init__.py
|   |   |       
|   |   \---ribbon
|   |           art.py
|   |           art_aui.py
|   |           art_default.py
|   |           art_internal.py
|   |           art_msw.py
|   |           art_osx.py
|   |           bar.py
|   |
```

Comment: ah thanks so much for this. I was told elsewhere to use `tree F > temp.txt` but it gave me some really weird data formatting (but still worked)

Comment: The `/a` tells it ASCII format rather than Extended ASCII.

Answer (score 0):

On a semi-related answer, I found a program that sort of does what I want to as well, in a different way

https://alternativeto.net/software/filelist-creator/

Basically, it creates an excel or .txt file with every FULL folderpath directory for everyname, which isn't too hard to process

So I could use this to format data as well too